# Problem with an angular filter of objects without using routes (Angular TS)

Tags: arrays, angular, filter, observable

I need some help about the code: I have to make a filter for a list of objects and I have to use the observables (the exercise only includes the front end part) and the objects are in a database.
    with the code written as soon as I insert a letter in the search bar, the array is emptied and only the last letter remains (for example insert C and after I insert E, in the filter only the E remains)

```
in TS:
Search(name:any):void{  

        this.arraycopy=this.mylist

        })
        this.arraycopy=this.mylist.filter(res =>{ 
            return res.description.includes(name.key) ; 
        })
 }

IN HTML:
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-2" *ngFor="let object of arraycopy">
        <div class="card">
           <div class="card-block">
               <p class="card-text">
                  <a class="breadcrumbLabelStyle" href="{{list.listCode}}" title="access to  {{list.description}}">{{list.description}}
            </a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>       
 </div>
```

Comment: Please post the complete code, including the "searchbar" and calls to the database

Comment: <input type="text" (keyup)="Search($event.target.value)">

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you're updating your Observable with the full search-bar input and not just the last key pressed?

You are probably updating it based on the keypress event which returns the last key pressed.

Update on Answer:

Try this:

Search-bar:

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="searchInput" (keyup)="Search()">
```

In TS:

```
  public searchTerm = new BehaviorSubject('');
  public searchInput: string;

      constructor() {
          this.searchTerm.subscribe((text: string) => {
              this.arraycopy = this.mylist.filter(res => {
                  return res.description.includes(text);
              });
          });
       }

       public Search(): void {  
           this.searchTerm.next(this.searchInput);
       }
```

This should work, but with this you're not using Observables so good.

Comment: in fact it only updates the last key, the problem is how to not update it like this

Comment: from how they told me I have to use observables

Comment: I forgot "this." when referring to searchInput variable in the first line of Search method.

Comment: Ok, now I noticed that you're updating the observable but you're using name.key to filter.

Give me one minute :)

Comment: the first line is a comment sorry,i deleted this

Comment: the page is white,disappears all

Comment: Press Control+Shift+J to open dev tools and see console logs and errors

Comment: hi davide,i am italian;can you contact me?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Unhandled Promise rejection: (SystemJS) XHR error (403 Forbidden)

Comment: I'm not sure but after searching on Google it seems can be a configuration problem.

Can you post your package.json, maybe you're missing something.